# How to create a dataframe that indicates the rows min and max of a given dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to produce a matrix as input for a conditional formatting for an automated chart creation process. My receiving colleague has to display the numbers and give the max and min of each row an associated color. For his process, a second matrix with entries that indicate the row mins and max would be ideal.
So what do I need to deliver?

Let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
Cat Product Brand1  Brand2  Brand3
A   a   6   9   5
A   b   11  7   7
A   c   9   5   5
B   d   7   3   10
B   e   5   8   8
B   f   10  6   6
C   g   8   4   4
C   h   6   2   9
C   i   4   7   7
```

From that, I want to generate the following dataframe, indicating "1" as row max and "2" as row min:

```
Cat Product Brand1  Brand2  Brand3
A   a   0   1   2
A   b   1   2   2
A   c   1   2   2
B   d   0   2   1
B   e   2   1   1
B   f   1   2   2
C   g   1   2   2
C   h   0   2   1
C   i   2   1   1
```

The indicators "1" and "2" could be something else, even letters or whatever. The zeros could also be na.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for replace values by mask created by [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['Cat','Product'])
m1 = df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0)
m2 = df.eq(df.min(axis=1), axis=0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(m1, 1, np.where(m2, 2, 0)), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
  Cat Product  Brand1  Brand2  Brand3
0   A       a       0       1       2
1   A       b       1       2       2
2   A       c       1       2       2
3   B       d       0       2       1
4   B       e       2       1       1
5   B       f       1       2       2
6   C       g       1       2       2
7   C       h       0       2       1
8   C       i       2       1       1
```

Another solution:

```
df = df.set_index(['Cat','Product'])
m1 = df.values == df.values.max(axis=1)[:, None]
m2 = df.values == df.values.min(axis=1)[:, None]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(m1, 1, np.where(m2, 2, 0)), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
  Cat Product  Brand1  Brand2  Brand3
0   A       a       0       1       2
1   A       b       1       2       2
2   A       c       1       2       2
3   B       d       0       2       1
4   B       e       2       1       1
5   B       f       1       2       2
6   C       g       1       2       2
7   C       h       0       2       1
8   C       i       2       1       1
```